# how can i implement injected wallet in dapps like metamask and trustwallet in React Native?

Tags: javascript, metamask, wallet, trustwallet

I want to implement the injected wallet feature just like done in Metamask and Trust wallet. when i open Dapps in my app it should provide a popup automatically asking to "Want to connect your wallet to example app"connect to my wallet. or when i click on the connect button on any Dapp like bakery swap or Pancake swap?

Comment: You mean you want users to give your app their public / private keys like they give them to MetaMask?

Comment: I want to connect the wallet of the user to the dapps, when they click on connect button in the popup during they load the website. gets connected with address of the user i think.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70833283/check-if-metamask-app-is-installed-on-the-phone-using-react-native